# Stange error when trying to migrate model changes django

Tags: django, django-models

I am just trying to migrate model changes that I have made to a django project and all I did was add two new columns to the model. Now I am trying to migrate it and I am getting this error below and I dont know where it came from or how to fix it... none of the files that are causing the errror in the traceback are familiar to me. Can anyone help.

Here is the error

```
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying tab.0027_auto_20170807_1753...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 318, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: tab_notification
```

here is my models.py file

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #server
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) #server
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200) #server
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    category = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #server

class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # server
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # server
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=NOTIFICATION_STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)  # server
    category = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=NOTIFICATION_CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=1)  # server
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # server

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # server
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='first')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='last')
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=45)  # user
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)  # user
    privacy = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)  # user
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # server
```

The only thing that i added was the first name and last name column to the models.py file.

Comment: did you have a model called tab_notification, but deleted it or renamed it?

Comment: no I never has a model called tab_notificaiton . that is why i am so confused as to where the error is comming from @almostabeginner

Comment: In that case, what columns did you add to which model?

Comment: all i added was the first name and last name to the profile column @almostabeginner

Comment: I don't even know why I asked that question lol.. From my experience the error message is thrown when you have stored objects of a model that has been deleted or its name has been changed. You could blindly delete the db.sqlite3 file at your project folder, delete all migration files except the init file, and then makemigrations -> migrate. This fully resets everything. Do this if you don't need any of the objects you've created, this deletes everything, have to recreate superuser also.

Comment: ok i will check to see if there is any objects that i need and try that. if i delete the last two or three migration files  and the run the makemigrations and migrate commands. would that work. or would i need to to delete all of the migration files.... @almostabeginner

Comment: i have only used it as a last resort, before i have tried deleting the last migration and deleting all objects of suspected model through shell etc before deleting all migration, dbsqlite...